# pyenv error when installing python version

Tags: python

I installed penv (2.3.17) on ubuntu 22.10. When i try to install any python version I get the error:

```
enjamin@bens-mini-note:~$ pyenv install 3.7.0
Downloading Python-3.7.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
error: failed to download Python-3.7.0.tar.xz

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.10 using python-build 20180424)

Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20230417084707.21389.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/python-build.20230417084707.21389 ~
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

Using sudo don't work ida with error: command not found.

Comment: If you change the default version of Python that came with the OS you will no longer have a functional OS and will need to re install.

Comment: I don't want to change the default version, I want to add a new version which sould be installed in ~/.pyenv/versions So I can use it to work with code which reqires a specific version.

Answer (score 5):

The answer I found on SO should help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67853440/5833429

See required dependencies for pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment

On ubuntu you need

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev curl \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the log, `curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination` means you have either run out of disk space, or there is a permissions error.

Since the `/tmp/python-build.20230417084707.21389 ~` suggests `pushd` was used to change into a new temporary directory created under `/tmp` before running `curl`, too little free space in your `/tmp` directory is the most likely cause.

Your `/tmp` directory is likely a small ramdisk.  You might be able to remove some old files from it.

However, there is also a `/var/tmp` actually on your disk you could use instead, by passing this to the command in the environment variable `$TMPDIR`, like this:

```
TMPDIR=/var/tmp pyenv install 3.7.0
```